# ¿Diferencia entre declarar String y [String]?

Tags: vb.net, variables

¿Alguien me puede explicar la diferencia entre estas dos declaraciones?

```
Dim linea As String
```

y

```
Dim linea As [String]
```

En Visual Basic .NET.

Gracias

Comment: No hay ninguna diferencia, hacen exactamente lo mismo. De hecho, si lo intentas hacer en Visual Studio 2017 te lo corrige y te lo deja como String sin los `'[' ']'`

Answer (score 2):

Los corchetes `[]` en VB.net permiten utilizar una palabra reservada como identificador.

En tu ejemplo no sirven para nada, y por ello como bien comenta @Marc, Visual Studio les elimina automáticamente.

Sin embargo, si servirían para lo siguiente:

```
Dim [String] As String
```

Como ves, los corchetes nos permiten usar la palabra reservada `String` como identificador de una variable.